# Another word for always feeling fortunate

Tags: single-word-requests

Consider these contexts:

- "I'm okay being paid less, because I feel fortunate to have a job when many are unemployed".
- A parent to a child - "Don't waste your food. There are many who don't even have it."

In the first case, a person is feeling fortunate/thankful in every situation,
and in the second, the person is forced to feel so.

I'm not sure if both cases are suitable for this question. I just wanted to know if there is any word to describe a person, who always feels fortunate/ grateful/thankful for any situation, or is forced to think so.

Comment: Not exactly the same meaning, but optimistic might come close for the first. The second is almost like the parent shaming the child into eating.

Comment: because I feel fortunate > "because I am lucky enough"

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you are asking. The last sentence, which seems to be the operative part of the question is about **always** feeling a certain way (or being pressured to so feel), but both examples are about **specific** occasions for feeling that way. Also it is not clear how to interpret 'I'm not sure if both cases are suitable for this question': it is **your** question, so you need to decide whether they are suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Someone who is always and overly optimistic is a *Pollyanna*.